# React implementation of Material Design with presentational components

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

Is it possible to use [Material UI](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui) with stateless components, or is state a requirement?

I intended to implement Popovers, and from what I gathered from the official [code example](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/popovers/) is that it's state-depenedent.

Comment: did React Popper not serve your needs? https://github.com/souporserious/react-popper

Comment: It's true, I could go directly for a library that serves that exact need. Especially react-popper seems to be great. But had preferred a library that covers more UX cases.

Comment: The modal has a certain UX use case, but within it, it's pretty UX flexible (depends on what you put into it). More here perhaps? https://reactcommunity.org/react-modal/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the Material UI component.

Some are ideal, and are recommended, as stateless components. In fact, many of the examples in the Material UI documentation use stateless components. For example, a `<Badge />` component:

```
const BadgeExampleSimple = () => (
  <div>
    <Badge
      badgeContent={4}
      primary={true}
    >
      <NotificationsIcon />
    </Badge>
    <Badge
      badgeContent={10}
      secondary={true}
      badgeStyle={{top: 12, right: 12}}
    >
      <IconButton tooltip="Notifications">
        <NotificationsIcon />
      </IconButton>
    </Badge>
  </div>
);
```

Or an `<Icon />`:

```
const HomeIcon = (props) => (
  <SvgIcon {...props}>
    <path d="M10 20v-6h4v6h5v-8h3L12 3 2 12h3v8z" />
  </SvgIcon>
);
```

Other components require them to be stateful to manage state like `open`.

And this is the case for the `<Popover />` component unfortunately.

```
export default class PopoverExampleSimple extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      open: false,
    };
  }

  ...
}
```

So, to answer your questions:

- Yes, it's possible to use a stateless component if the component does not require state
- No, it's not a requirement to use a stateful component, unless the component requires state